# SQL Count based on value in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to do two counts of a column based on the content of another column in a different table.

```
SELECT WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONTYPE
   , IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE
   , COUNT(IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE) AS 'Shipment'
   , COUNT(IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE) AS 'Reciept'
   , CAST(MTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONDATE AS DATE) AS DATE
FROM WMTRANSACTIONHEADER 
  INNER JOIN WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL ON WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.ROWID = WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_TRANSACTIONHEADER 
  INNER JOIN IMITEM ON WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_ITEM = IMITEM.ROWID
```

Forgive me for how unreadable it is, but generally, I'm trying to count ITEMSUPCCODE based on whether TRANSACTIONTYPE is either an 'R' or an 'S'. Any tips/ideas would be great!

EDIT:

Unfortunately I underestimated this task and the importance of other fields. So let me explain this more in depth. I am making a report that counts the daily ITEMSUPCCODE fields. There are 8 ITEMSUPCCODE fields that are possible, and we want a count of each one. So the perfect report would group all the transactions in a day, then group by each entry in ITEMSUPCCODE, and then count each entry in ITEMSUPCCODE, based on what is in TRANSACTIONTYPE. I apologize for not being clear, I thought the counting part was the only issue I had!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be a big help.

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm not sure what kind of sample data you'd be after, but generally there are 8 entries for ITEMSUPCCODE, and we just want to count them and display that count in a report based on the transaction type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this if I am getting your question right: Below query is not tested

```
With tmp AS(Select WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONTYPE, IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE,
CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATE, MTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONDATE)) Date; 
FROM WMTRANSACTIONHEADER INNER JOIN WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL
ON WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.ROWID = WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_TRANSACTIONHEADER 
INNER JOIN IMITEM ON WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_ITEM = IMITEM.ROWID
WHERE TRANSACTIONTYPE in ('R', 'S'))

select count(ITEMSUPCCODE) , Date, Transactiontype
from tmp
group by Date, Transactiontype
```

You can change count(ITEMSUPCCODE) or count(DISTINCT ITEMSUPCCODE) based on your requirement.

Comment: This also looks promising, although it is grabbing an 'A' transaction type, but that's easy enough to deal with, thanks!

Comment: Okay I decided to try it out now, one issue, I also need to group it by date, unfortunately I didn't see this being an issue, and I was very wrong. I'm trying to CAST the date from being DATETIME to being just Date, and it is ruining the groupings.

Comment: Will this work: count(IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE) OVER (PARTITION BY WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONTYPE, CAST(MTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONDATE AS DATE)) and in where add transaction type IN ('R', 'S'). let me know

Comment: It doesn't throw any errors, but the results just look like this
``AA 1
AA 1
AA 1
AA 1
AA 1``, AA being taken from some other field I have selected that isn't relevant, taking that field out just outputs the numbers.

Comment: This is fantastic! Thank you, here is a bit of the results ```6 2020-07-22 00:00:00.000 R AA
20 2020-07-22 00:00:00.000 S AA
2 2020-07-23 00:00:00.000 S AA```

The only remaining thing is that I need to have the ITEMSUPCCODE displayed, but I believe I have that taken care of.

Comment: We're just confirming if the data is accurate now, but I managed to, I believe, get everything I needed from that query! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach with the result in rows instead of columns.

It also allows you to count how many distinct IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE there are in your table

```
Select count(distinct IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE),  --count of distinct values in the group
       count(IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE),           --non-distinct values
       TRANSACTIONTYPE
  FROM WMTRANSACTIONHEADER 
 INNER JOIN WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL
    ON WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.ROWID = WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_TRANSACTIONHEADER 
 INNER JOIN IMITEM
    ON WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_ITEM = IMITEM.ROWID
 where TRANSACTIONTYPE in ('R', 'S')
 group by TRANSACTIONTYPE
```

Comment: This one may be exactly what I want, I'll have to play with it tomorrow to make sure the data is accurate, but this does seem correct.

Comment: Okay I decided to try it out now, two issues, I also need to group it by date, unfortunately I didn't see this being an issue, and I was very wrong. I'm trying to CAST the date from being DATETIME to being just Date, and it is ruining the groupings. Secondly, I need the ITEMSUPCCODE to be counted per ITEMSUPCCODE, there are 8 different entries and I need to know the amount of each. Sorry that this is becoming more confusing!

Comment: On the grouping by date: do you want a date value per (milli)second or per day or per month? That determines what transformations to do with the date column. One value per day would just be the cast of the date column to a `date` datatype. One value per month could be done with `datefromparts(year(datecolumn), month(datecolumn), 1)`. The count the ITEMSUPCCODE per ITEMSUPCCODE is confusing to me. Do you want to just group by ITEMSUPCCODE and have a count(*) column? or a `count(case when transactiontype = 'R' end)` column?

Comment: It's trying to see totals by day, so I need the date per day.

The ITEMSUPCCODE confuses me too, don't worry. There are 8 values that can be in the ITEMSUPCCODE field, and we want to count how many of each of those exist there are for each an S and R in TRANSACTIONTYPE field. For instance, one of the fields is "WIP SORTED", and we want to know how many "WIP SORTED" there are for a day, broken down by whether or not it is an S or an R.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I often use a subquery like this:

```
select 
    NameLast, 
    (select count(*) from Paychecks where Paychecks.EmployeeID = Employees.ID) As PaycheckCount  
from Employees
```

The inner join isn't needed for the subtable.

Reworking your original query, I think this should work:

```
SELECT WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.TRANSACTIONTYPE, IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE, COUNT(IMITEM.ITEMSUPCCODE) AS 'Shipment',
(SELECT COUNT(ITEMSUPCCODE) FROM IMITEM WHERE WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_ITEM = IMITEM.ROWID) AS 'Reciept'

FROM WMTRANSACTIONHEADER INNER JOIN WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL ON 
WMTRANSACTIONHEADER.ROWID = WMTRANSACTIONDETAIL.R_TRANSACTIONHEADER
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Without that last join it does get upset, but I appreciate that example query, I'm sure that'll be helpful moving forward.